# SQL Doctrine year's eve

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

that's is strange, maybe is my fault. Today I launch my test and 2 of they faults (yesterday dont). This test use a control date of some bookings, and I presume the problem is that today is 31/12. I'll show you the code:

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
        $query = $em->createQuery(
            'SELECT b
            FROM AppBundle:Booking b
            WHERE b.bookingDate >= CURRENT_DATE()
            AND b.bookingDate <= CURRENT_DATE()+1
            ORDER ASC b.bookingDate'
        )

        return $booking = $query->getResult();
```

That way is the only way i found to check that the booking have a date at today. Is possible that this fault becouse today is 31/12? Do you have some solution?
sorry for bad english, thanks.

Comment: Please add which DB are you using. Paste the error text.

Comment: @LucioM.Tato I use MySql. i don't have an error, but my test fault. This code shoud find 2 booking with today date (31/12) but not found that. Yesterday the test found that 2 booking with date of yesterday (30/12)

Comment: i think that "WHERE b.bookingDate >= CURRENT_DATE()
            AND b.bookingDate <= CURRENT_DATE()+1" have problem with 31/12-1/1

Comment: Bad English is not the problem. You left important information out of your question. [edit] your question to add that information. Also, are you certain the 2 bookings with today's date are in the table? Perhaps something else went wrong and they weren't added. Finally, your `WHERE` clause is slightly wrong. When you compare to `CURRENT_DATE() + 1` you should use strictly less than `<` ***not*** less or equal.

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the dates by Php:

```
$today = new DateTime('now');
$tomorrow = new DateTime('tomorrow');

$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$query = $em->createQuery(
            'SELECT b
            FROM AppBundle:Booking b
            WHERE b.bookingDate >= :today
            AND b.bookingDate < :tomorrow
            ORDER BY b.bookingDate ASC'
);

return $query->setParameters(array(
    'today' => $now->format('Y-m-d'), 
    'tomorrow' => $tomorrow->format('Y-m-d')
))->getResult();
```

You can avoid var `$booking` and return result directly.
Also you have missed `;` at the end of `createQuery` and ORDER is ORDER BY.

Also beware with namespaces, maybe you must to use `new \DateTime('now');`

Answer (score 1):

```
CURRENT_DATE()+1
```

returns

```
20161232
```

which seems to be pretty wrong.
A way to make it works as you want it to would be this:

```
DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

which returns

```
2017-01-01
```

Comment: today my code works, and i presume the problem is not that you think, because i don't see the bug at 31/10, only 31/12. But i insert the date like this DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), 1, 'day') ad i think is better than before